# gridview cells are not aligned properly when an image and text are inserted

Tags: android, gridview

I inserted an image and a text to the grid view. The gridview cells are not aligned properly. I don't understand why this is happening. This is the getview

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView=null;
    TextView textView = null;

    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int imgSize = 0;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
      //  grid = new View(mContext);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single,null);
         textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
          imgSize=size.x;
     //   textView=new TextView(mContext);
       // imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    //    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imgSize/2, imgSize/2));
   //     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

     //   imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
     //   imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        textView.setText(menus[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    } else {
       // imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        view = convertView;
    }
   // textView=new TextView(mContext);

    return view;
   // return grid;
}
```

This is the grid layout

```
<GridView
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid"

    />
```

This is the imageview and textview layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="9sp" >
</TextView>
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jko7F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your grid Item layout as below -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```